# Getting "cannot use import statement outside of a module" errors and don't want to upgrade Node

Tags: node.js

I have started to get cannot use import statement outside a module errors all of a sudden when adding code to my backend and now it is asking to change the style of my imports from what it was before.

I have seen other questions where it recommends upgrading node however as I have had previously ran into errors with newer versions and version 12.13 was previously problem free I don't want to change it again.

What is likely to have caused this problem? Would I be best removing new code?

The code I have added was from a MongoDB exmaple using mongoose whereas I my app is using Sequelize and Postgres.

```
\user.controller.js:3
import errorHandler from "../helpers/dbErrorHandler";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

```
//previous code in file
exports.siteAdminLevel = (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Site admin content.");
};

// new code in file

exports.userByID = async (req, res, next, id) => {
    try {
        let user = await user.findById(id).populate('following', '_id name')
            .populate('followers', '_id name')
            .exec()
        if (!user)
            return res.status('400').json({
                error: "User not found"
            })
        req.profile = user
        next()
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status('400').json({
            error: "Could not retrieve user"
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What was the change that was made that led to "all of a sudden"?

Comment: I have added in new api's to a controller with code from a text book. They were previously "exports.siteAccessLevel = (req, res) => { etc" and the new ones I am using async " exports.create = async (req, res) => { etc" for each method.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what is causing the error though. Is this to do with different versions of ES?

Comment: I don't know what could be causing but I do suggest you rollback your code and see if that fixes it. Then you'll know for sure. This is one good reason to have code in a local Git